# ¿Como colocar toolTip en fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fullcalendar

Estoy implementando `fullCalendar js`, ya logró mostrar los eventos en mi calendario de la siguiente manera:

```
    <script>

    $(function(){
        GetDaysCalendar();
    })

    function GetDaysCalendar() {

        $.get('/Vacaciones/ObtenerDiasCalendario')
        .done(function(data){

            var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var eventsList = data;

            eventsList.forEach(event =>{
                const { idDia, dia, tipoDia, descripcion } = event;

                if (tipoDia === "Feriado") {
                    eventsList.push({
                        'id': idDia,
                        'title': descripcion,
                        'start': dia,
                        'allDay': true,
                        'color': '#FF0404',
                        'textColor': '#FFFFFF'
                });
                } else if (tipoDia === "No Feriado") {
                    eventsList.push({
                        'id': idDia,
                        'title': descripcion,
                        'start': dia,
                        'allDay': true,
                        'color': '#0C92C8',
                        'textColor': '#FFFFFF'
                    });
                }

            })

            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                locale: 'es',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                events: eventsList
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
       
    }
</script>
```

Ahora lo que quiero es colocar un popOver para poder ver la descripción del evento, estuve revisando en al documentación de [EventRenderHooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) que se puede hacer con evento `eventDidMount` y estuve viendo que forzoso necesitava los siguientes scripts:

- https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js
- https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js

Lo hice de la siguiente manera pero no me funciona:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                locale: 'es',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                eventDidMount: function (info) {
                    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                        title: info.event.extendedProps.title,
                        placement: 'top',
                        trigger: 'hover',
                        container: 'body'
                    });
                },
                events: eventsList
            });
```

Pero no me muestra nada y tampoco un error, espero me puedan ayudar a ver mi error.